# $-1$ is not a sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

The question is the following:
Prove that $-1$ is not the sum of two squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

I have a solution which makes use of Algebraic Number Theory, namely the Dirichlet Unit Theorem about units in a number field. Hopefully this solution is correct.

Suppose that $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ with $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. By working in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm 7})$, we can factor this as $(x+iy)(x-iy) = -1$, where $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. It follows that $x+iy$ is an element with complex absolute value $1$, for any embedding $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm 7}) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, so by the Dirichlet Unit Theorem it follows that $x+iy$ is a root of unity, which must be inside $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\pm 7})$. However it is not too difficult to find that those are $\pm 1, \pm i$ and those do not give solutions to the equation.

However I am wondering if there is a more elementary solution to this problem, especially one that does not require the use of the Dirichlet Unit Theorem.

Comment: I don't think your solution works as stated, note that $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$. You should be able to do this by observing that $x^2+y^2=-1$ holds in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7}, i)$.

Comment: @N.S. the OP did say they're working in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\pm 7})$.

Comment: Your proof is not so clear. How do you deduce exactly that $x+iy$ must be a root of unity? Consider the equation $(x+iy)(x-iy)=1$ in the same field: this has infinitely many solutions, because you can solve Pell's equation in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{7})$. For example, $x=8$ and $y=3i\sqrt{7}$ is a solution.

Comment: Oops, I've made a mistake there. Indeed it doesn't follow that $x+iy$ must be a root of unity, so this approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: One way to do this is to observe that $\sqrt{-7}\in\Bbb{Q}_2$ is a 2-adic integer. After that it reduces to proving that $-1$ is not a sum of squares in the residue class ring $\Bbb{Z}/8\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that we dealt with this very question once. Gimme a minute.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114411/11619) is the thread I had in mind. This is close to being a duplicate, but as I answered that one I should not use my dupehammer without support from others.

Comment: That's a really nice answer to the question! I will certainly remember this as a nice trick. Do you know by chance if there's an even more elementary answer, in particular one that does not require the use of $2$-adics?

Comment: Jan, in the linked thread WimC maps the problem into $\Bbb{Z}/8$ without going through the adics, I think.

Comment: @Ferra The OP is confusing $K$ and $O_K$. If $a\in O_K$ and $|\sigma(a_j)|=1$ for all embedding $\sigma_j:K\to \Bbb{C}$ then the coefficients of $f_n(X)=\prod_j (X-\sigma_j(a^n))\in \Bbb{Z}[X]$ are bounded independently of $n$, thus for some $m,n$, $f_n=f_m$ and hence $a^l = a^n$ which means that $a$ is a root of unity. $\frac{2+i}{\sqrt{5}}$ is not an algebraic integer, it is not a root of unity even if all its conjugates have absolute value $1$.

Comment: Without $p$-adics: Write $x=a+b\sqrt{-7}$ and $y=c+d\sqrt{-7}$ to get
$$a^2+c^2-7(b^2+d^2)=-1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 2(ab+cd)=0.$$
Reducing the former mod $8$ shows that precisely one of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ is congruent to $2$ mod $4$ and the rest is odd. But then the latter is not satisfied, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elementary solution that shows that $-1$ is not a sum of squares from $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$. 
Assume  $\sum_k (a_k + b_k \sqrt{-7})^2 = -1$ that is
$\sum_k (a_k^2 - 7 b_k^2) =-1$ and $\sum_k 2 a_k b_k = 0$, adding the last two equalities we get
$$\sum_k (a_k + b_k)^2 =-1 +8 \sum_k ( b_k)^2$$

so a sum of three squares $\equiv -1 \pmod 8$, not possible.

Comment: For all integers not for rationals which further constrains the validity of such restrictions. Regards..

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- With abstraction about whether the unit theorem is correctly applied above, a more elementary demonstration matching rational and non-rational parts seems to give something unlikely. In fact from
$$\begin{cases}x=a+b\sqrt{-7}\\y=c+d\sqrt{-7}\end{cases}$$ one has
$$x^2+y^2=-1\iff a^2+c^2-7(b^2+d^2)=-1 \text{ and }2(ab+cd)=0$$ from which the system in $a^2$ and $b^2$
$$\begin{cases}a^2-7b^2=7d^2-c^2-1\\a^2b^2=(cd)^2\end{cases}$$ whose solution is
$$2a^2=7d^2-c^2-1\pm\sqrt{(7d^2-c^2-1)^2-28cd}\\14b^2=-(7d^2-c^2-1)\pm\sqrt{(7d^2-c^2-1)^2-28cd}$$ This is very restrictive for two reasons: $a$ and $b$ must be rational and exchanging the unknowns for $c$ and $d$ the solution in a and b must have the same form.

Comment: This seems to be closely related to sum of three squares theorem, but I cannot see how to use it.

Comment: @N. S..-Perhaps. Anyway we have $a^2+b^2+c^2=8b^2+7d^2-1$ Unfortunately $8b^2+7d^2-1=4^n(8m+7)$ have solution; for example $n=0$ and $d=8k$ or $d=8k+4$ which goes without saying that we would be restricting to integer instead of rational values.

Comment: Reducing $a^2+c^2-7(b^2+d^2)=-1$ mod $8$ shows that one is even and the other three are odd, contradicting $2(ab+cd)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be put under the general headline  "elements of a field $K$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ which are represented by a non-degenerate quadratic form with coefficients in $K$", see e.g. Cassels-Fhröhlich, ANT, exercise 4 at the end of the book. In the simple case of 2 or 3 variables, it is more convenient to adopt the **normic** point of view.

So fix $K$ and introduce the biquadratic extension $L=K(\sqrt a, \sqrt b)$, whose 3 quadratic subextensions are $K(\sqrt a), K(\sqrt b), K(\sqrt ab)$. Here $K=\mathbf Q, a=-1, b=7, ab=-7$, and your question is equivalent to a NSC for $c=-1\in \mathbf Q(\sqrt {-7})$ to be a norm from $L$. The general normic criterion is that *a given $c\in K\subset K(\sqrt ab)$ is a norm  from $L$ iff $c$ is a product of a norm from $K(\sqrt a)$ and a norm from $K(\sqrt b)$.* A detailed proof is given in exercise 4.3 *op. cit*. Applying this criterion, we get that $-1$ is a sum of two squares in $\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-7})$ iff $-1\in \mathbf Q$ is a product $(x^2+y^2)(u^2-7v^2)$, with $x,y,u,v \in \mathbf Q$. *If* the coefficients were in $\mathbf Z$ (but *a priori* they are not), one could conclude by comparing modules and using the Pell-Fermat equation (or Dirichlet's unit theorem). Isn't some hypothesis missing ?

Because the 4-variable equation above, say (E), admits rational solutions, as can be shown by "elementary" ways. First pick up a rational solution of the equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (a pythagorean triangle). Eq. (E) then reduces to $(u^2-7v^2)=-r^{-2}$, or, changing variables but keeping the same notations, $u^2-7v^2=-1$, which admits rational solutions (Pell-Fermat).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be restated in terms of quadratic forms representing $0$. 
Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$.

Here, $F= X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2$ is the quadratic form to consider. It arises, naturally when considering $a,b,c \in \mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})}=\mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{-7})/2]=:R$ such that 
$$
\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{c}{b}\right)^2 = -1.
$$

It is true that $F=0$ has no solution in $R$ other than $(0,0,0)$.
A proof follows by the Infinite Descent Argument below.

Let $(a,b,c)\in R^3\setminus\{0,0,0\}$ be a putative solution  to $F=0$ such that $gcd(a,b,c)=1$, here we use that $R$ is a PID. Let $\mathfrak p_2$ be any prime ideal of $R$ containing $2$.

Then $R/\mathfrak p_2^2\simeq \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and the points $(0,0,0), (0,0,2),(0,2,2),(2,2,2)$ are the solutions of $F=0$ in $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ (up to change of coordinates). Thus, $a,b,c\in \mathfrak p_2$ i.e., $\mathfrak p_2 \mid gcd(a,b,c)$. This contradicts the assumptions above.

**Remarks**:

1. In $2$-adic terms one deduces that $F=0$ has no non-zero solution in $\mathbb Z_2$  (or $\mathbb Q_2)$.
2. Local-global principles (Hasse-Minkowski theorem) apply to the quadratic form $F$. As a consequence, if $F=0$ has no solution in $K$ then there must be a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $K$ such that $F=0$ has no non-zero solution over the localization (or completion) $K_{\mathfrak p}$ of $K$ at $\mathfrak p$.